# Transactions in plaid - categories

Tags: plaid

I'm looking to build a budgeting app where users can categories transactions (i.e. entertainment, rent, utilities, etc).

Is it possible to categorize plaid transactions by needs/wants? aka rent is under the need category, restaurants are under a want category.

I've looked here but am struggling to find any info: https://plaid.com/docs/api/products/#auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `/categories/get` endpoint to see all the categories used by Plaid. From there, it should be pretty straightforward to essentially create a mapping where for each category you classify it as a need or a want. (This is a determination you'd have to make yourself; need/want info is not built into the API.)